# How to fix a fake USB flash drive that reports more space than actually exists?

Tags: usb-flash-drive

I bought a USB flash drive that reports it has more space than it really does.

1. How can I determine how much space it really has?
2. Can I format it properly if I can get the above answer?
3. Should I just return it and not try to salvage it?

Comment: @Appleoddity Sadly [this is a common scam](https://superuser.com/questions/834124/can-i-let-my-fake-flash-usb-drive-get-its-real-capacity-through-low-level-format). I would recommend the original poster just complain and return the drive… If possible. People who sell drives like this typically hack thyme USB flash drives to rip people off. Also, whoever downvoted this needs to read the question I am flagging this as a dupe of. This is a valid concern in a bad situation. Check out the [F3 (Fight Flash Fraud) tool](https://github.com/AltraMayor/f3).